# Radio buttons in django Forms

Tags: django

I'm having difficulty settings up the forms.py file to include a radio or select button. I looked at the documentation but was having no luck applying the correct syntax.

Here is what I currently have in `forms.py`--

```
from django import forms

class PictureForm(forms.Form):
    like = forms.ChoiceField(???)
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField()
```

And in my `views.py` --

```
from app.forms import PictureForm

def index2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PictureForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            Picture.objects.create(like=cd['like'], name=cd['name'], email=cd['email'], message=cd['message'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect ('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = PictureForm()
    return render_to_response('index2.html', {'form':form},)
```

How can I set up a set of radio buttons of 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'? 
How to do this with a select dropdown? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Look at setting the field's `widget` and `choices` when writing the form class.

```
from django import forms

class PictureForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [
        ('1', 'Option 1'),
        ('2', 'Option 2'),
    ]
    like = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=CHOICES, 
    )
```

- The default `widget` of [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField) is a [drop down select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select).
- The `choices` argument has the same format as the one of a [model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#field-choices).

Comment: The first item in the (tuple) is the value and second is the label to be shown on the radio button.

Comment: the widget should not be called, only passed with `widget=forms.RadioSelect` instead, as the [official docs show](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget)

Comment: Can this be integrated with `CreateView`?

Comment: @ScottSkiles Yes see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27322032/1417624

Answer (score 7):

Remember to remove all the external styling, and then add the code below:

```
CHOICES = [('M','Male'),('F','Female')]
Gender=forms.CharField(label='Gender', widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES))
```

The above code generates Radio buttons.

In my case, I was using a `style.css` file which was forcing the radio button to render as a list.