# Override a Django generic class-based view widget

Tags: django

Say I have a basic CreateView form, like this, to allow new users to register on a site:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import CreateView

User = get_user_model()


class Signup(CreateView):

    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
```

I just tried this, and found that the password field is rendered in plain text; how would I go about overriding the view so that it uses forms.PasswordInput() instead? (I realise it's probably easiest to just define the form by hand, but I'm just curious about how you'd do that.)

Comment: you should call it in modelForm

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could override `get_form()`, and modify the form to change the widget on the password field:

```
from django import forms

class Signup(CreateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(Signup, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput()
        return form
```

But an even better way would be to just create a custom form class. In the custom class just set `widgets` on the `Meta` class. Like this:

```
from django import forms

class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput()
        }

class Signup(CreateView):
    form_class = SignupForm
    model = User
```

Usually you would put the custom form class in a forms.py file as well.

Comment: I like the way you are doing in views.py, +1, have you ever tried this?

Comment: Yes I have. I would rather make a separate class for the form though. Seems cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! The second approach works for me, but when I do the first one I get `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_form'`.

Comment: Oh my bad. I forgot to put `self` in the call to super. Should be like `super(Signup, self).get_form(form_class)`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ah yeah, I just realised what was missing after looking over some other code. `super` still mostly feels like black magic to me. Thanks again!

Comment: Implementing `get_form` is only 4 lines vs 7 lines for making a subclass of `ModelForm`. I'm curious - why do you think making that subclass is a better choice?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this affected earlier versions of Django, but in more recent versions the `get_form()` should have a default `form_class=None` when overriding that method.

The updated (Python 3, Django 2.2) example would be:

```
from django import forms

class Signup(CreateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput()
        return form
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin

Comment: form_class=None worked for me :) Supplements the answer of @jproffitt