# Is it possible to add placeholder in generic Create view form?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

This is my models.py file

```html
class Report_item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    image = models.ImageField(default="add Item image")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + "      " + str(self.publish)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('feed:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date"]
```

I add the generic Create view from from model in my template. The views.py file is the following:

```html
class ReportCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Report_item
    fields = ['title', 'item_type', 'location', 'city', 'image', 'Description']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.owner = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return FormMixin.form_valid(self, form)
```

I want to add a placeholder in my form. Is it possible to add the placeholder in generic Create view form? Please add one placeholder for the one field and rest I will do.

Comment: Do you mean a default value?

Comment: I mean this one <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"> placeholder we use in html form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For generic views, you can do that:

```
class ReportCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Report_item
    fields = ['title', 'item_type', 'location', 'city', 'image', 'Description']


    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()

        form = super(ReportCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['field_to_add_placeholder'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your placeholder'})
        return form

    # rest of the class...
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321692/override-a-django-generic-class-based-view-widget) and see [docs on widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput).

For `ModelForm`, see [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) of the doc. You can override the default fields and in this case the widget by adding a placeholder attribute:

```
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter your name here'}),
        }
```

Comment: I have this one create view class ReportCreate(generic.CreateView): when I tried to add meta in this view nothing happen.

Comment: You specifically asked for `ModelForm`, I'll edit my answer for your generic view.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. Yes please help me.

Comment: class ReportCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Report_item
    fields = ['title', 'item_type', 'location', 'city', 'image', 'Description']

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(ReportCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['title'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your placeholder'})
        return form
   

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.owner = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return FormMixin.form_valid(self, form)

Comment: I do this but I am getting Server Error (500) from this.

Comment: You need to give the logs of the error for us to be able to help. Depending on your version of Django, maybe replace `form = super(ReportCreate, self).get_form(form_class)` by `form = super().get_form(form_class)`

Comment: Actually, there was nothing in the log except this "GET /report HTTP/1.1" 500 27
. I am using Django 1.11. Let me try this one. You know I am developing this application for society and you are contributing to it. Thanks .

Comment: Did you import `forms`? `from django import forms`

Comment: Yes I did but do I need to do anything in the forms.py file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178762/discussion-between-imsaiful-and-cyrlop).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, @cyrlop, your answer is great. But I found this more suitable if someone doesn't want to change the type of the widget that is taken from the model itself

```
class ReportCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Report_item
    fields = ['title', 'item_type', 'location', 'city', 'image', 'Description']


    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()

        form = super(ReportCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['field_to_add_placeholder'].widget.attrs ={'placeholder': 'Your placeholder','class':'someclass'}
        return form
```