# How can I get user selected radio option? Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model named UserAddress and a form created from the same model which is UserAddressForm.

```
class UserAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city =  models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone =  models.CharField(max_length=120)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_address()
    def get_address(self):
        return"%s,%s,%s,%s" %(self.address, self.address2,self.city,self.phone)
```

I am displaying all the user addresses in the html with a radio check-box. I want to get the user selected address in my view and assign to another model instance which I am unable to figure out. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924988/radio-buttons-in-django-forms

Comment: Yes I have already seen this and I am asking something different. Basically, in my view I am creating a new Order and when i do new_order.shipping I want to get the user checked option and want to assign it. I am unable to figure out how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your models structure is following:

```
class UserAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city =  models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone =  models.CharField(max_length=120)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_address()
    def get_address(self):
        return"%s,%s,%s,%s" %(self.address, self.address2,self.city,self.phone)


class Order(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress)
```

You can make a form based on Order model, put `ModelChoiceField` and specify widget to be `RadioSelect`

```
from django import forms


class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    address = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=UserAddress.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.widgets.RadioSelect(),
    )
```

In that case when you handle `OrderForm` submit you will have address which user is choose.

Comment: I have tried it in this way too and it works.                            shipping_address = forms.ModelChoiceField( 

queryset=UserAddress.objects.filter(type="user"),

widget = forms.RadioSelect,

empty_label = None,

)