# Django fields in form

Tags: python, django, image, web

I am a beginner in Django, hence this might be a simple issue. But I'm not able to get past this successfully.

This is my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Fabric(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    name_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=None)
    loc_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=None)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Images(models.Model):
    design_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    cost_price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fabric = models.ForeignKey(Fabric, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    selling_price = models.FloatField()
    aliveness = models.IntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    set_cat = models.IntegerField()
    set_cat_no = models.IntegerField()
    set_cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I'm building an apparel management database system which contains cloth designs. 
My forms.py is

```
class ImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Images
    fields = ('file','cost_price','set_cat_no','set_cat_name',)
```

My views.py

```
@login_required
def uploadphoto(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {}

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImagesForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():

        image = form.save(commit=False)

        image.save()

        return render_to_response(request,'cms/upload-photo.html', {'upload_image': form})
    else:
        print form.errors

else:
    form = ImagesForm()
    context_dict = {'upload_image': form}

    return render_to_response('cms/upload-photo.html',context_dict, context)
```

My upload-photo.html is

```
{% block main %}

<form id="upload_form" method="post" action="/zoomtail/upload-photo/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ upload_image }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

1. The problem here is when I goto /upload-photo/ I don't see the drop-downs to the foreign keys to categories, fabric and manufacturers. I have read that it should be automatically generated but I don't see any.
2. And `selling_price` has to be calculated based on the given percentage increase from the cost_price which has to be entered in the form. How do I do this? And `aliveness` of an apparel has to be set by default as 1. How to do this?
3. `set-cat` field of an apparel is 1 if it belongs to a set and 2 if it belongs to a catalogue. How do I get a radio button asking whether set or catalogue and that to be captured as an integer in the database?
4. And design-id field of an apparel has to be a string which contains abbreviations of category, fabric, manufacturer, etc etc all the fields it belongs to. How do I do this dynamically?

I know, this is a very long question but I'm a newbie and these are literally giving me headache since days. I shall be very thankful to those who answer this.

Comment: You'd be better to ask separate questions rather than asking for help for 4 different issues. Firstly, don't use `render_to_response`, it's obsolete. Use `render` instead. For your first issue, you haven't included `'category'` in `fields`, so it won't be included in the form.

Comment: add the fields in the fields in ImagesForm class

Comment: Okay it works, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I believe the issue with the dropdown is that you've excluded the fields from `ImageForm`. You have:

   `fields = ('file','cost_price','set_cat_no','set_cat_name',)`

   but should have:

   `fields = ('file','cost_price','set_cat_no','set_cat_name', 'category', 'fabric', 'manufacturer`,)`

   if that doesn't  work, are there any options in your database for `Categories`, `Fabric`, and `Manufacturer`? If your tables are empty, the dropdown will be empty. If there are values in the database, is there HTML being generated but the label value is blank (i.e. `<option>{this is blank}</option>`)? In django, you can override the `__str__` function to specify how the dropdown options get labeled

Override `__str__` as follows:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

2. You can compute the value of `selling_price` and any other computed value in the block `if request.method == 'POST'`.

Example:

```
def uploadphoto(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ImagesForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        #- Calculate value(s) here -#

        if form.is_valid():

            image = form.save(commit=False)
            image.save()`
```

3. Please see [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924988/radio-buttons-in-django-forms) for using radio buttons
4. You would do this in the same place as #2 above

Comment: Thank you. For 2 and 4, can you give the exact code of the functionality?

Comment: I have asked it again here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849734/querying-based-on-form-input-and-string-operations-in-django