# Querying based on form input and string operations in django

Tags: django, database

[Django fields in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841850/django-fields-in-form/50845891#50845891)

As question 4 in that describes, I need to get the form input and calculate design-id for each image uploaded. How do I query the database to get the abbreviation for category, fabric, manufacturer and manufacturer location and concatenate all these strings to generate and store the design id?

I have added this code in my `views.py`

```
image = form.save(commit=False)

cat = Category.objects.get(name=image['category'])      
fab = Fabric.objects.get(name=image['fabric'])
manu = Manufacturer.objects.get(name=image['manufacturer'])
setcat = Group.objects.get(name=image['set_cat'])
string = cat.abbr + "-" + fab.abbr + "-" + manu.name_abbr + "-" + manu.loc_abbr + "-" + image['selling_price'] + "-" + setcat.abbr + "-" + image['set_cat_no']
image['design_id'] = string

image.save()
```

This is giving me the error - 'Images' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

My Images model in `models.py` is this

```
class Images(models.Model):
    design_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    cost_price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    fabric = models.ForeignKey(Fabric, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    selling_price = models.FloatField()
    aliveness = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    set_cat = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    set_cat_no = models.IntegerField()
    set_cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    visit_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have tried returning unicode() from `__unicode__` but this didn't work too.

Comment: Please do it yourself, if you have any errors, ask for help.

Comment: I have edited the question with the error I'm getting.

Comment: Someone please answer. Need this urgently.

Comment: please describe your error more precisely

Comment: can you print `image` in debug? is it possible to get data by `image['cateogry']` way? I think you should use `image.cleaned_data` or sth else

Comment: Error is 'Images' object has no attribute `__getitem__`.

Comment: image.cleaned_data isn't working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't access model instance attributes via dictionary notation. You need to use dot notation, as you have done everywhere else.

```
image.design_id = string
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error even after trying this.  Images' object has no attribute `__getitem__`

Comment: Because you're doing it at various places in the code, this was just an example. You should read the error message. For example `Category.objects.get(name=image.category)` and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I changed in all those places and got the same error.

Comment: You need to *post* the error and the full traceback.

Comment: Sorry, it worked. I hadn't changed everything. Thanks.