# Displaying images in django template

Tags: html, django

I am querying images from the database and displaying them in HTML.

My views.py is

```
@login_required
def viewall(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    images = Images.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    return render_to_response('cms/view-all.html',{'images':images,'media_url':settings.MEDIA_URL},context)
```

My view-all.html is

```
{% extends "cms/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    View-all
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{%  for image in images %}
    <img src="{{ media_url }}{{ image.file }}">
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

In settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
```

My images are in the project directory file /media/images.

But the images aren't getting displayed. I'm getting like this.

[image]

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Can you share the image src path by inspecting the images?

Comment: <img src="/media/images/images/zt4_oYssTH8.png">

Comment: Images is there 2 times. How do I take one out? Where exactly might is that extra images being added?

Comment: possible in image.file since media url is /media/. check your Database

Comment: What should I check in database?

Comment: <img src="{{ image.url }}"> will provide path including media root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add media url to project's urlpatterns:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

See details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

Comment: Okay, It worked. Thank you so much. Shall be thankful if you can take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849734/querying-based-on-form-input-and-string-operations-in-django

Answer (score 0):

try this, u need to add "." before path ( assuming media folder is in root directory )

```
MEDIA_URL = './media/'
```