# How to pass choises from views.py in forms.ChoiceField?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I want to make a form for online tests, but I can't figure out how to make radio buttons (forms.ChoiceField or similar) with the transfer of the selection value not from forms, but from views. Why can't you get from models directly in the form? because I do not know in advance which pk is needed.

Please tell me an option that will help you create a form for online testing. I ask with examples to make it easier to understand. Thanks in advance.

```
class Course(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='***')
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='url', unique=True)
metadesc = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Meta description', default='***')
content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='****')
colLec = models.IntegerField(max_length=255, default=0, verbose_name='***')
Lect1 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='****')
Lect2 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='****')
Lect3 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='***')
Test1 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='***')
Test1_1 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='***')
Test1_2 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='***')
Test1_3 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='****')
Test1_4 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='***')
Test1_5 = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='***')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = '***'
    verbose_name_plural = '****'
    ordering = ['title']
```

Comment: can you show us your `models.py`

Comment: Here you go..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924988/radio-buttons-in-django-forms

Comment: Added models, but why?

Comment: There is no solution to the problem at the specified link, the specified code is not called from views.py, and when trying to do this it says "'ChoiceField' object is not callable"

Comment: Why not make a radio button in html or javascript and just grab that choice with views.py and pass it to whatever you want?

Comment: Can you give a link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/

By doing it in models you would do some thing like this..
**Models.py**

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    NAMES=  [
        ('foo', 'Foo'),
        ('bar', 'Bar')
    ] # choices can be defined elsewhere
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True,choices=NAMES)
```

In the same app, make the forms
**Forms.py**

```
from .models import Thing

class Thingform(forms.ModelForm):
    NAMES=  [
    ('foo', 'Foo'),
    ('bar', 'Bar')
    ] # choices still need to be defined here, since we are overriden a wiget, so it would be best to define choices in one location

    name = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=NAMES)
    class Meta:
        model = Thing 
        fields = '__all__'
    name.widget.attrs.update({'class':'foo'}) # adding class to the <ul> widget
```

Then render the form in views

```
from .forms import Thingform

def your_view(reqwuest)
    ...
    form = Thingform()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form})
```

Dont forget your css to remove the ugly bullet points

```
.foo {
    list-style:none;
}
```

======================================================
Now you can do it a **quick and dirty way** which I dont reccommend, one primary reason for code readability. Going by the documenation, you can theoretically do it all in `views`. Like the following..

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django import forms


def index(request):
    CHOICES = [
        ('new_foo', 'New Foo'),
        ('new_bar', 'new bar')]
    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'foo'}), choices=CHOICES) # dont forget styling
    class InViewForm(forms.Form): pass #most simplest form

    form = InViewForm()
    form.fields['name'] = choice_field # access form fields attr
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Until views work, I don't know what should be in the selection options.
I tried using ChoiceField, but it didn't work to pass the value there from views.
If you do, "otv1 = forms.CharField (widget = forms.RadioSelect)", then how to pass a value from views to it?
initial = {'otv1': course.Test1_1}
form_class = TestForm
form = form_class (initial = initial)
but in the html form, only the title of the widget is displayed, but not course.Test1_1, and if you remove widget = forms.RadioSelect, then it is successfully displayed as a regular input text with the text from the course.Test1_1 field

Comment: The problem is that the options are contained in several fields of the model, but not any will do, but under a specific pk. How to get from the model field for a specific pk? There are a lot of options, but I only need to pull 4 out of a specific pk.

Comment: I found not a dirty solution! In views, you can write "form.fields ["Test1"] = choice_field" and it will make the fields I need.

Thank you very much friend!