# How to extract value from Radio Button in views.py in django from request.POST method

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, radio-button

I'm trying to get value of a **Radio Button** from HTML template into views.py file for storing it inside my model. The problem is that it returns "on" always, and I'm using "request.POST['btnradio']" method to get the value/label of my radio button which has name="btnradio" in views.py file. I want it to return that the value/label of that button which is checked. Like if the button with value/label "Foodie" is checked, then it should return "Foodie" so that I can store it in modal. Likewise, if the other one is selected, then it should return "Restaurant".

This is my HTML template where I've written a form in which I'm trying to get value from a user signup.

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="signUpForm">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="userName" class="input-box" placeholder="User Name" required>
    <input type="email" id="uemail" name="userEmail" class="input-box" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" id="upass" name="userPass" class="input-box" placeholder="Password" pattern="^\S{6,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Must have at least 6 characters' : ''); if(this.checkValidity()) form.ucpass.pattern = this.value;" required>
    <input type="password" id="ucpass" name="userCpass" class="input-box" placeholder="Confirm Password" pattern="^\S{6,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter the same Password as above' : '');" required>
    <div class="radio-btn-div btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
        <input type="radio" id="btnradio1" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" autocomplete="off" checked> <!-- This part I'm talking about -->
            <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="btnradio1">Foodie</label>
        <input type="radio" id="btnradio2" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" autocomplete="off"> <!-- This is the second radio button -->
            <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="btnradio2">Restaurant</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="signupBtn" class="btn" value="Signup">
</form>
```

This is the views.py file.

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username    = request.POST['userName']
    email       = request.POST['userEmail']
    password    = request.POST['userPass']
    cpass       = request.POST['userCpass']
    userType    = request.POST['btnradio']
    User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=password, userType=userType)
    # and rest of the code is not important
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925240/4942661). I think this resolve your question

Comment: No, it will not work in my case. Since I'm using only views.py file to check the value/label.