# how to put radio buttons from admin.py or models.py? without using forms.py

Tags: python, django

I have a doubt; what happens is that in my form I want to put radio buttons in the "country" field, only I don't know how to do it because to make this section I'm using admin.py and models.py; Do you know if I can place radio buttons via models or admin?

> admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
   add_form = UserCreationForm
   form=UserChangeForm
   model=CustomUser
   list_display = ['pk','email','username','first_name','last_name']
   add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets+(
       (None,{'fields':('alternativeContact','country','address')}),
   )
   fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets+(
       (None,{'fields':('alternativeContact','country','address')}),
   )



admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

> models.py

```
COUNTRIES=(
   ('EUA', ('EUA')),
   ('Canada', ('Canada')),
   ('Other', ('Other')),
)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   alternativeContact=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=0,choices=COUNTRIES)
   address=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=0)
```

> html

```
<div class="row mb-3">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="mb-3">
         <label class="form-label d-block mb-3">Country :</label>
         {{ form.country }}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Radio buttons in django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924988/radio-buttons-in-django-forms)

Comment: hello! thank you; I'm just looking to not use forms.py, because I would have to edit: add_form = UserCreationForm and
    form=UserChangeForm from admin.py. I think it is very confusing if I use forms.py and maybe I can destroy something that is already working

Comment: It does not matter too much where you put your forms class. You can also put in `admin.py` if that works better for you. Just create your own form that inherits from `UserChangeForm` and change the type of the field to a radio button. I guess need to also do this for `UserAddForm`